# Recommended and/or legitimate library sources

Tags: dart

I have observed that the src files for a Dart library are placed in the `lib/src/` directory or subdirectories. Is this the recommendation?

Could my lib src files be placed under Dart's web directory as well?

I am asking because I have the following source files under a subdirectory of web:

```dart
import 'package:dart_web_toolkit/ui.dart';

import 'packages/epimss/shared.dart';
import 'packages/epimss/resrc.dart';

import './onset_view.dart';
import './site_view.dart';
import './mediating_factors_view.dart';
import './duration_view.dart';
```

My current file is `pain_view.dart` in the same directory as the last four imports above. However I found that only the first current import can be referenced - the others generate a warning that

> The different imported libraries 'onset_view.dart' and 'duration_view.dart' should not have the same name '').